# Image_tag displaying image url instead of image on page

Tags: ruby, image, imagemagick, paperclip

So I am using imagemagick and paperclip to upload images and use the following code in the controller to set the path and url of the image:

```
has_attached_file :image, :path => 'app/assets/images/storeimages/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename', :url => 'app/assets/images/storeimages/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename', :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ }
```

Then in the view I am displaying the image with the following code

```
<%= image_tag @storeitem.image.url(:medium) %>
```

I'm not sure why it is displaying the name of the image instead of displaying an image because when I don't set the path and url, it saves where imagemagick originally sets it and displays it.

Comment: are you sure that your image was saved to your asset's path? Check this image in directory manually, if it's present, then attach code from your migration.

Comment: Check the HTML output, most likely the image is not found and you see the "alt"

Comment: The image is definitely there I can see it in the folder manually and when I upload images with different file names, it displays the different file names